# Automatic adaptation of a Composite added to runtime in a SashForm

Tags: java, swt

My software, Java, uses a basic plugin system, each plugin allows you to extend a method that inserts runtime objects into a Composite, name "content" in the code and with BorderLayout, into a SashForm, to allow the user to manage the plugin's options.

What happens is that in the Preferences window, the new elements don't automatically adapt to the window remaining with size 0 and therefore invisible.

The only way I managed to make them visible using setBounds ()

This is an implementation of the method by which plugins create their controls in the Preferences window

```java
class TestPref extends PreferenceNode{
        public TestPref(){
            System.out.println("Creating plugin preferences");
            setTitle("Test plugin");
        }

        @Override
        public void popolatePreferenzeComposite(Composite _composite, Properties _workbenchProp, Properties _userProp) {
            Label lblPrometeoTestPlugin = new Label(_composite, SWT.NONE);
            //lblPrometeoTestPlugin.setBounds(10, 10, 430, 15);
            lblPrometeoTestPlugin.setText("Prometeo Test Plugin v.1.0.0");

        }
    }
```

This is a method of Preferences window that populates the content when the user clicks on the tree menu item.

```java
// Prometeo->Plugins
        String itemPrometeoPlugins=ApplicationLauncher.texts.getString("com.gega.prometeo.workbanch.preferences.tree.prometeo.plugins");
        tree.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                if(tree.getSelection()[0].getText().equals(itemPrometeoPlugins)) {
                    clearContent();

                    Table table = new Table(content, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
                    table.setLayoutData(BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
                    table.setLinesVisible(true);

                    TableColumn tblclmnNome = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
                    tblclmnNome.setWidth(100);
                    tblclmnNome.setText("Nome");

                    TableColumn tblclmnVersione = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
                    tblclmnVersione.setWidth(100);
                    tblclmnVersione.setText("Versione");

                    TableColumn tblclmnStatus = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
                    tblclmnStatus.setWidth(100);
                    tblclmnStatus.setText("Status");

                }       
            }
        });
public void clearContent() {
        for (Control control : content.getChildren()) {
            control.dispose();
        }
    }
```

without setBounds
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbALc.jpg)
with setBounds
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaKeO.jpg)

thank you very much to everyone

Comment: This seems very strange, it is not at all clear what you are doing here. Why are not just using the normal `PreferencePage` based preference pages?

Comment: There is no default preference page because the software is from scratch and I am using SWT only as graphics libraries outside of Eclipse.

Comment: PreferenceNode is JFace. If you are using that you can use all the JFace Preference code - PreferenceDialog, PreferencePage, PreferenceManager, ....

Comment: PreferenceNode is mine class, only the name is the same

Comment: In which case you should have made that much clearer in the question, and provided a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using setBounds () in this way

table.setBounds(0,0,content.getBounds().width,content.getBounds().height)